# Cast to larger type in switch case

Tags: c, embedded

During work i saw the following code snippet and now i wonder, if there is a reason for casting the "case-values" to a larger datatype. I guess, that it is used to offer the possibility of having more than 256 different states later on, but then, the state variable must also be larger.
Here is the code i am talking about:

```
#define STATE_1 (uint8_t)(0x00)
#define STATE_2 (uint8_t)(0x01)
...
#define STATE_n (uint8_t)(0x..)

void HandleState(uint8_t state)
{
  switch(state)
  { 
    case (uint16_t)STATE_1:
      // handle state 1
      break;

    case (uint16_t)STATE_2:
      // handle state 2
      break;

    ...
    case (uint16_t)STATE_n:
      // handle state n
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Is there another reason for this?

Comment: It might be intended to enforce `unsigned int` type promotion for the compares, but `unit16_t` is not guaranteed to be the same size either and just casting `state` would be sufficient. Perhaps the state codes were `enum` labels in a previous version? These are by default `int` - but even then the casts make little sense imo.

Comment: Is that for C or C++ actually??

Comment: So, why added the C++-tag? Note that these are different languages!

Comment: I thought of a conceptual reason which affects both

Comment: Well, as you might have gotten from a comment, the answer might very well vary. Note that in C `const` is just a promise by the programmer not to change a _variable_, while in C++ it is a true constant value (i.e. possibly without an actual address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a slightly failed attempt to get rid of implicit integer promotions on a 8-bit or 16-bit microcontroller.

First of all, there is no way integer promotion can cause harm here, so preventing it is overly pedantic and just reduces readability. At a glance it looks like nonsense.

But.

Perhaps the coding standard used enforced that no implicit conversions are allowed? Which for example MISRA-C does. In that case, the code suddenly makes sense: they wished to surpress warnings from their static analysis tool.

Using explicit casts would then also be a way of demonstrating that you are actually aware of implicit type promotions (something that only a handful of C programmers are, sadly) and that you handle them in your code.

But if so, the programmer missed out one integer promotion taking place, namely here: `switch(state)`. This is how switch statements work:

> The integer promotions are performed on the controlling expression. The constant
>   expression in each case label is converted to the promoted type of the controlling
>   expression.

So if the programmer was concerned about implicit promotions, they should have written the code as `switch((uint16_t)state)` and then also kept the casts in each `case`.

---

If you sneered at the code in the question, consider the following:

- Do you actually know what implicit promotions there are in a switch statement and did you consider what impact they might have on this code?
- Do you know the meaning of the integer promotion rules? Did you know and consider that an `uint8_t` will get promoted to a (signed) `int` in this code?
- Do you use a coding standard and static analysis tools at all, yourself?

Comment: you are right, this code based on the guidelines of MISRA-C and the company developing this code does use static analysis tools. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> Is there another reason for this?

No.

It's either a mistake, muppetry, or legacy (perhaps `state` and the macros used to be something else, but this particular code never got changed?).

I'm voting for muppetry, personally. Sometimes you run into code that somebody else wrote that is bad code, and that's just the way it is.

Comment: alright, i do not think about it any more since it does not influence the program semantically

Comment: Turns out that the "muppetry" here was the original programmer following  industry-standard coding guidelines and using static analysis. Sounds very much like a professional embedded programmer. If you have never worked with a coding standard or static analysis yourself, and is therefore dismissing the code, since you are not accustomed to that level of formality and professionalism... that's too bad.

Answer (score 1):

That just looks like bad style all around. You should have a single typedef for state:

```
typedef uint8_t State;
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
#define STATE_1 (State)(0x00)
#define STATE_2 (State)(0x01)
...
#define STATE_n (State)(0x..)

void HandleState(State state)
{
  switch(state)
  { 
    case (State)STATE_1:
      // handle state 1
      break;

    case (State)STATE_2:
      // handle state 2
      break;

    ...
    case (State)STATE_n:
      // handle state n
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Then if you later find you need `uint16_t`, you only need to change one line.

Comment: Still litte sense. The casts might suppress warnings actually.

Comment: You are right, but this does not answer my question. As i did not implement this, i like to know if there is a reason for that

Comment: `const State STATE_1 = 0x00;` Get rid of those macros.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This works for C++ only, this is C. Even for C++, using `enum` would be the better approach.

Comment: @Olaf: Dammit I keep forgetting about that. C doesn't let that be used in constant-expressions, does it. As for `enum` well no, `enum class` maybe, but the original coder obviously wants his constants to have a very specific size.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I just use the `enum` for the constants, not for the type of variables as such (I use something like `typedef uint16_t StateType;` for the variable types just following the enum),  **if** I really need a specific size for such variables. `#define`s are imo much worse here.

Comment: @Olaf: Oh, so would I

Comment: @Olaf So do you have a suggestion as to how I can improve my answer code?

Comment: Nothing for now I have not written in my answer. I just see not much sense in any casts here, except if you hate your compiler or prefere assembler-style (no types;-).

Comment: @Olaf Storing hex literals in an enum is a very bad idea, because a hex literal is guaranteed to be of type `unsigned int`, while an enumeration constant is guaranteed to be of type (signed) `int`. And then there are the enum variables themselves, for which there are no guarantees at all.

Comment: @Lundin: Can you point me at where the standard states a _hexadecimal constant_ is `unsigned int`? [6.4.4.1p5 and 6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5) actually tells different. If I undesrstand this correctly, _decimal constants_ cannot be `unsigned`, but non-decimal constants use standard promotion, starting with `(signed) int`. For the `enum` type itself, there is very well a [guarantee](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p4): The type is such that all values of all members can be represented.

Comment: @Olaf Ah right, I got that mixed up, no guarantee but they _can_ be of unsigned type. They are indeed of the largest type they can fit in. The difference with hex constants is that if they can't fit in an int (for example 0x80000000) they will be of type unsigned int.

Comment: @Lundin: Yepp! I do agree, however, `enum` is very versatile - in theory- but has been rendered useless for many applications "by definition" (aka "the standard"). If they had added just the simple feature to specify its integer type (which would also have to be used for the members), would have made that much more useful. E.g.: `enum my_enum : uint8_t { ...`. I really hoped thy would have included that in C11.

Answer (score 1):

It might be intended to enforce unsigned int type promotion for the compares, but unit16_t is not guaranteed to be the same size either and just casting state would be sufficient.

Perhaps the state codes were enum labels in a previous version? These are by default int - but even then the casts make little sense imo.

Note that the casts even possibly suppress warnings about inappropriate size. Best would be to use an enum, or `#define` the labels just unsigned, e.g. `0x00U` without fixing the type.